# Can an ant walk towards or away from a point with a polygon obstacle?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry, shapes

[image]

Given a polygon S and a point p that lies outside S, imagine an ant that can only follow a straight line towards or away from p.

For some shapes (Fig. 1), there is a choice of p such that the ant can move unobstructed in at least one of the two possibilities: towards (T) p, or away (A) from it. This condition corresponds to any ray cast from p intersecting the perimeter of S exactly 0 or 2 times.

However, for the same shape (Fig. 2) there may also be points that lead to blocked (B) regions, where the ant will bump into the polygon whichever direction it tries to move in. For yet other shapes (Fig. 3) there may be no choice of p that leads to no blocked regions. Having blocked regions corresponds to some rays cast from p that intersect the perimeter of S more than 2 times.

Is there an algorithm that determines whether a p exists that satisfies the condition for some given polygon S? If such points exist, can it also determine the region that contains them?

Comment: Not sure about _Fig. 3_: is _p_ allowed to be infinitely far from _S_? (Are all contained in a finite (& square?) space?)

Comment: @greybeard - Very good point. I would like p to be a finite distance from S. But even if it is allowed to be infinitely far, there are still shapes that are unsolvable, e.g. an H with two extra holes on the sides.

Comment: I was thinking 1) no holes 2) conditions on the shape of _filling pieces_ between _S_ and its convex hull: please argue how this is but a pure geometry problem.

Comment: @greybeard It's an algorithms problem in the field of computational geometry. If people think it's out of scope here I can move it somewhere else ... programmers.stackexchange perhaps?

Comment: Each pair of edges will give some area (possible empty) of points p which satisfy "there are blocked regions" condition.  Union of all such areas for every pair of edges will give the answer.

Comment: This problem belongs to the class of Visibility. It has been extensively studied. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visibility_polygon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find all concave corners of the polygon obstacle. For each corner, extend its two edges infinitely. The sector between these two rays, and also (as Nico Schertler pointed out) the point-reflected region of this sector, define where the point must be so that the obstacle does not hide the corner form the point's rays.

[image: straight lines, polygon obstacle]

In the example with the L-shaped obstacle, there is one concave corner. The sector between its neighbouring edges (top right) and its point-reflection (bottom left), form a region (indicated in red), where the point must be.

In the example with the U-shaped obstacle, there are two concave corners, and the two corresponding regions (red and blue) have an overlap (purple). The point must be in this purple region.

In the example with the S-shaped obstacle, there are two overlapping regions (purple). The point must be in one of these two regions.

In the example with the H-shaped obstacle, the red and blue region have an overlap (purple) above the horizontal beam of the H, the blue and green region have an overlap (teal) to the right of the horizontal beam, the green and yellow region have an overlap (lime) below the horizontal beam, and the yellow and red regions have an overlap (orange) to the left of the beam; however, there is no overall overlap between the four regions, and no place where the point can be that will satisfy the constraints.

Comment: You sould also include the point-reflected regions (because you can also walk away from the point). This will give you some valid positions also in the right example.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Indeed, I overlooked that. Thanks for the tip!